# The form outputs an empty response and nothing is sent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

It is very necessary to make this form send the name and phone number from the site. When I try to send data-after clicking the send button - I see an empty modal window instead of a response - sent or not.
Contents of the file send.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}

    $to = "recipient@gmail.com";
    $sendfrom   = "sender@mail.ru";
    $headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    //$subject = "$formData";
    $message = "<br><b>Имя пославшего:</b>". $name ."<br><b>Телефон:</b>". $phone;
    $send = mail ($to, $headers, $message);
    if ($send == 'true')
    {
        echo '<p class="success">Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p class="fail"><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!</b></p>';
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "Попробуйте еще раз";
}
?>
```

HTML form.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/feedback/remodal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/feedback/remodal-default-theme.css">
<a class="mainButton" href="#modal">Callback</a>

<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1Title" aria-describedby="modal1Desc">
 <div class="remodalBorder">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
      <form id="form">
        <form action="../php/feedback/send.php" method="POST">
        <p><span class="formlable" style="text-transform: uppercase;">You name</span><br>
            <input type="text" class="putName" name="name"  cols="67%" placeholder="Required field" required>
        <p><span class="formlable" style="text-transform: uppercase;">Phone number</span><br>
            <input name="phone" type="tel" class="putPhone" placeholder="Required field" required>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Order a call">
            <input type="hidden" name="formData" value="Application from the site">
        <br><br>
By clicking on the "Order a call" button, you give <a class="mainArticlesTextAgree"  href="../agreement.html">consent to the processing of</a> your personal data.  
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/feedback/remodal.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/feedback/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: `<form id="form">
        <form action="../php/feedback/send.php" method="POST">`two `form` action ??

Comment: This error when you insert happened once
<form id="form"> - This shouldn't be happening
it would be better to help than dislike

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested forms in your HTML, nested HTML form is not allowed as mentioned by @Abdulla Nilam and the working draft of HTML5:

[From the html5 working draft](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element):

> **4.10.3 The form element**
>
> **Content model**:
>
> Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

to make it work you should remove the first form since it have no action or method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/feedback/remodal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/feedback/remodal-default-theme.css">
<a class="mainButton" href="#modal">Callback</a>

<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1Title" aria-describedby="modal1Desc">
 <div class="remodalBorder">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
        <form id="form" action="../php/feedback/send.php" method="POST">
        <p><span class="formlable" style="text-transform: uppercase;">You name</span><br>
            <input type="text" class="putName" name="name"  cols="67%" placeholder="Required field" required>
        <p><span class="formlable" style="text-transform: uppercase;">Phone number</span><br>
            <input name="phone" type="tel" class="putPhone" placeholder="Required field" required>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Order a call">
            <input type="hidden" name="formData" value="Application from the site">
        <br><br>
By clicking on the "Order a call" button, you give <a class="mainArticlesTextAgree"  href="../agreement.html">consent to the processing of</a> your personal data.  
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/feedback/remodal.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/feedback/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now when you click on the button nothing happens

Comment: Do you have a script attached to form with ID `form`, I will update my answer to include the ID just in case, try it with the new snippet.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this HTML Form**

```html
<a class="mainButton" href="#modal">Callback</a>
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1Title" aria-describedby="modal1Desc">
  <div class="remodalBorder">
    <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
    <form id="form" action="../php/feedback/send.php" method="POST">

      <p><span class="formlable" style="text-transform: uppercase;">You name</span><br>
        <input type="text" class="putName" name="name"  cols="67%" placeholder="Required field" required>
      </p>
      <p><span class="formlable" style="text-transform: uppercase;">Phone number</span><br>
        <input name="phone" type="tel" class="putPhone" placeholder="Required field" required>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Order a call">
        <input type="hidden" name="formData" value="Application from the site">
      </p>
      <br><br>
      By clicking on the "Order a call" button, you give <a class="mainArticlesTextAgree"  href="../agreement.html">consent to the processing of</a> your personal data.
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain why your answer  is relevant to the OP's Question.

Comment: Sorry about that, but the explanation is simple that @Heretic has used two form tags of which is nested and that is not allowed and no action is defined in the first form tag. <form id="form">